# Trouble modifying a codepen

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop, pixi.js, codepen

This is the codepen that I want to modify: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdzPoe

The end goal is for it to display a random image from an array instead of only one image.

I created an array with 2 images for a start and I get a random image from it:

```
let allLogos = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2d/Google-favicon-2015.png/150px-Google-favicon-2015.png","https://image.prntscr.com/image/0zOeSOZJQPKLFkD3OS9oLA.png"];
let randomLogo = allLogos[Math.floor(Math.random() * allLogos.length)];
let texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage(randomLogo);
```

I tried putting the `texture` inside a `for` at the `class FaceCloud` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Edit: Here (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpWeRd?editors=0010) it takes a random image from that array and uses that for all images but what I need is for each displayed logo to be random.

I need to integrate this inside the `for` below somehow.

Edit: When I just move it inside `for` it seems to get a random image and its size is displayed correctly but it always displays only the first loaded image?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrVLBJ?editors=0010

Comment: Are you trying to get it to show two different images at once (randomly picking which image is which)? Or to show a single image, as it currently does, but randomly pick which image that is?

Comment: @Andrea Show two different at once. Or however many there is inside the `allLogos` array.